# Automatic Import (daily, csv & xls --> xls(m))

Tags: excel, vba, csv

C 
Dear SO-Community

i've got the following problem/challenge:

I need to automatically and daily import some data into one "master-xls". Both the source data and the consolidated data is organised in the same structure (plz have a look at the examples below)

Is it possibe, either way -  with VBA (preferable) or without VBA - to automatically import data from the source files (file name is a combination of a string and the actual date) into the "destination-file"

Help and tips are very much appreciated! Plz point me into the right direction instead of presenting an already working example.

It is important, that the data from the new source file is appended to the data which is already existing!

best wishes,
Luke

source files:
*[source 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9219a4tg4ixcmi6/string20140907.csv?dl=0)
*[source 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44br841xzn6tt5h/string20140908.csv?dl=0)

master file
*[master xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoqzrnwjhbm2ai7/Master.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've finally managed to automate the csv import. 
some parts of the solution are originally found here:
http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

below is my solution:

```
Sub listfiles_dir()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastcolumn As Integer

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Dim header As Boolean
header = True

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("raw")
ws.Activate

ws.Cells.ClearContents

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(".\data")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data")


i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    'Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    'Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1

    Debug.Print (objFile.Path)

    If header = True Then
        lastrow = 5
    Else
        lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'gets you the last row
    End If

    Call import_csv(ws, objFile.Path, header, lastrow)

    lastcolumn = ws.Range("$A$" & CStr(lastrow)).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
    Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn) = objFile.Name

    Debug.Print (lastcolumn)

    If header = True Then
        header = False
    End If

Next objFile

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


'import files


Sub import_csv(sheet As Worksheet, fname As String, header As Boolean, row As Integer)
'
' importCSV Macro
'
Dim startingrow As Integer
startingrow = 1

If header = False Then
    startingrow = 2
End If

Debug.Print ("$A$" & CStr(row))



With sheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fname, Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$" & CStr(row)))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    '.PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    '.SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFileStartRow = startingrow
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to point you in the right direction, assuming I understand you correctly.

If you're opening up and wanting to read from an Excel spreadsheet, this will be useful:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

'Set up the Connection to Excel
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" 'or whatever your provider is
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source="C:\My_source_file.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';"
    .Open
End With

'Set up the command to get all that mess out the spreadsheet.
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [WhateverSheetHasMyData$]"
End With

'Load up the recordset with everything in the worksheet.
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
With rst
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open cmd
End With
```

This should get you going in the direction you'd like to go. I am sure you can extrapolate from this how you might also use a command to deposit the data you've loaded into some other document, such as another spreadsheet or a database table.

Also, when it comes to appending the information, Excel has a nifty thing:

```
...
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 'wb being your workbook object; you could also use the sheet name instead of the index here
ws.Activate
lastrow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(11).Row 'gets you the last row
```

So, you can use that lastrow+1 value as the starting point for your insert.

As an aside,

> "Help and tips are very much appreciated! Plz do not bother to point me into the right direction..."

^ Generally not a good thing to say around these parts. Especially when you just said "I appreciate your help, but please don't bother helping me."

Have fun with this.